# html table column width changes with new rows added

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with html/php. I have a table with 7 columns. Data for the columns comes from a sql database and therefore it is quite dynamic. Using jquery, I've added the option to expand/collapse specific parts of the table. The expanded part has one column more, like this:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
    <td>Col3</td>
</tr> <!-- this part can be expanded or collapsed -->
```

However, whenever I expend or collapse the second row, the first one will change its size, despite there being more than enough space to fit the second row into the first one.

So the question is: How can I make the table so that the first row will get an automatic width, which all other rows will adapt to? Specifically, I want all columns to be the width of the ones in the first row:

```
-------------
|c1   |c2|c3|
-------------
|c1|c2|c3|c4|
-------------
|c1   |c2|c3|
-------------
```

Comment: You should show how you expand/collapse... And your table should have all cells on a row (you talked about 7, but what you posted show 3 or 4) even if those are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess that you mean space on the page and not number of columns. If that's the case, use css.  Something like

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Take a look at the following guides:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout
https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

If this isn't what you mean then take a look at [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). They've got all this stuff figured out already!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 columns on the first row and you add a second row with 1 column, but you specify the length or make it on the whole screen, that will change the upper row as well. The table has to be 1 whole, with 1 whole width. If you make one row "500" that will increase all the rows, respectively if the row with 1 column gets increased, than the row with 2 columns will be increased as well. Since the length has became more, the columns need to make up for it, because they have to be to the end of the row.

If you want to have 2 rows with a different width, you need to make 2 tables.